# bcachefs - how to setup a ssd only volume

Tags: linux, filesystems, storage, ssd, network-attached-storage

I stumbled across bcachefs a few days ago.
After some research, I still have a few questions.
As I understand it, only the foreground_target must be defined.
Does it make sense to set up a foreground_target or a metadata_target in a pure SSD configuration?
I'm considering using bcachefs as a storage solution for a NAS (via NFS) with a replication factor of 2.
How do you calculate the available storage if, for example, a metadata_target is used?
And the last question... does the filesystem reliably show the available disk space? For example, some distributed file systems have problems in this area.